# How do I test a code in a sub-sub-directory?

Tags: unit-testing, rust

In Rust, how do I test a code in a sub-sub-directory, with `cargo test` command?

```
program
 `─ src
 |   `─ main.rs
 `─ tests
     `─ foo
         `─ foo.rs
```

main.rs:

```
fn main() {
}
```

foo.rs:

```
mod test_foo {
    #[test]
    fn test_foo() {
        assert!(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you read the [testing section of *The Rust Programming Language*](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/testing.html)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One way would be to create `tests/tests.rs` with the following contents:

```
mod foo {
    mod foo; // this will include `tests/foo/foo.rs`
}
```

If you run `cargo test` after this, it will run the `test_foo` test function:

```
$ cargo test
     Running target/debug/tests-0b79a5e208e85ac6

running 1 test
test foo::foo::test_foo::test_foo ... ok

test result: ok. 1 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `#[path = "foo/foo.rs"]`, like this:

Source layout:

```
.
├── Cargo.toml
├── src/
└── tests/
    ├── tests.rs
    └── foo/
        └── foo.rs
```

tests/tests.rs:

```rust
#[path = "foo/foo.rs"]
mod foo;
```

tests/foo/foo.rs:

```rust
mod test_foo {
    #[test]
    fn test_foo() {
        assert!(true);
    }
}
```