# How do you run groups of test by directory or regular expression in Rust?

Tags: testing, rust

In `rust` running `cargo test` runs all (unit, doc, integration, etc) test. Or you can run specific test using [filters](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch11-03-test-organization.html) [(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54585804/how-to-run-a-specific-unit-test-in-rust). I don't see a way to run specific groups of test unless all test are in one file.

For example with `node.js` and `mocha` you can run test in groups. If I only want to run end-to-end test, I setup a custom `mocha-config-e2e.js` file and set test directory like `spec: 'src/**/test-e2e/*.test.js'`. Then do something like `"test-e2e": "NODE_ENV=test mocha --config ./mocha-config-test-e2e.js"` in `package.json`. Now when i want to run all end-to-end test, I can run `npm run test-e2e` from the terminal. I can repeat this for any group I create.

How do I do the same thing in `rust`? How do I run groups of test by directory or regular expression?

Basically I'm looking to run `cargo test-e2e` or `cargo test-e2e-feature_group1` or something similar where a command runs all test specified by directory or regular expression. [This reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37626348/how-do-i-test-a-code-in-a-sub-sub-directory) shows how to make test in sub-directories run but doesn't reveal how to run specific groups of test.

```
├── src
├── tests
│   ├── e2e
│   │   ├── feature_group1
│   │   │   ├── example1.rs
│   │   │   ├── example2.rs
│   │   │   ├── example3.rs
│   │   ├── feature_group2
│   │   │   ├── example1.rs
│   │   │   ├── example2.rs
│   │   │   ├── example3.rs
│   ├── integration
│   │   ├── example1.rs
│   │   ├── example1.rs
│   ├── e2e_feature_group1.rs
├── Cargo.toml
```

The closest I have been able to get is with something like this in `tests/e2e_feature_group1.rs`:

```
#[path = "e2e/feature_group1/example1.rs"]
mod example1;
#[path = "e2e/feature_group1/example2.rs"]
mod example2;
...
```

Then running `cargo test --test e2e` for all test in `tests/e2e/feature_group1` that I add to the `e2e_feature_group1.rs` file. But that requires creating a `tests/[group_name].rs` for every group and listing every test that is in the directory instead of using an expression to catch all test in a directory.

Instead it would be nice to call `cargo test --regex "tests/e2e/feature_group1/*"` or `cargo test --config "test_config_e2e1.rs"` and put the regex `#[path_regex = "e2e/feature_group1/*"]` and any other test config I want to run in that file.

Comment: Have you tried the `--test` option?

Comment: If `cargo test e2e::feature_group1` doesn't work for you, could you [edit] to more clearly explain why? I can imagine situations where it might not work, but it looks like it would work for your example.

Comment: Unless I missed something the ```--test``` option only test a specific file and wouldn't test all groups of test unless all test were in that file.

Comment: @DanGetz ```cargo test e2e::feature_group1``` didn't work for me but I don't know why and I don't see documentation showing why it should work. Running that code does not execute all test in ```tests/e2e/feature_group1 ```. Even if I put ```test_e2e.rs``` in ```test/``` I'm still limited to running test in one file using ```--test``` or running all test with ```cargo test```

Comment: @jtlindsey ah, sorry, I see I've confused with tests under the `src` directory (organized by module). That works for those, not for tests under `tests` apparently.